# Calculating percentiles in Excel

Tags: excel, function, percentile

In cell C1 I need the 95th percentile of 25th April i.e matching only the number corresponding to 25th April starting from cell B10. The number of values corresponding to 25th April is going to change weekly, so it isn't always going to be from the range A10:A15.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the AGGREGATE() Function:

```
=AGGREGATE(16,6,$B$10:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))/($A$10:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))=B1),$E$1)
```

The two `INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))` sets the extents of the data.  so no matter how large the list grows or shrinks it will be included.

The 16 makes the AGGREGATE() Function do the PERCENTILE.  The 6 ignores errors, this is important as we are going to force errors.

The part under the `/` forces the errors.  Any date that does not match the date for which we are looking returns 0 and dividing by 0 returns an error and gets ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in C1:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(IF($A$10:$A$15 = $B$1, $B$10:$B$15),.95)
```

When you have entered the formula, press Ctrl-Shift-Enter, which tells Excel to treat it as an array function. The IF clause in this mode lets you determine a subset of an array with given criteria.